# Persistently mount remote filesystem? i.e. SSHFS/mosh?

Tags: sshfs, mosh

I work with a very large remote filesystem, so I like to use mosh instead of ssh for low-connectivity persistent connections, or just when my computer sleeps. 
For editing files though, I mount the remote filesystem with SSHFS so I can use my computer's native GUI editor.

mosh is a great alternative to ssh to create persistence, but is there a similar thing for SSHFS or remote filesystem mounting?

Comment: I know you mention a GUI editor, but I know that `vim` supports editing remote files natively (`vim scp://username@host//path/to/the/file`.  I believe there are GUI editors with similar capabilities; I'm a `vim` guy, but I work with folks who use SlickEdit and intelliJ (and its brethren), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you add

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 0
```

to the end of `~/.ssh/config` it will send a package every 60 seconds to keep your connection alive, and it will keep doing so forever.